# Django migration error while trying to migrate

Tags: python, django, django-admin, migrate

I created an app two days ago, added some models, and migrated successfully. And since, I haven't added or changed anything but I added something today and tried to migrate, after making migrations and tried to migrate, I got this error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, students, user_upload
Running migrations:
  Applying user_upload.0002_users_upload_phone_number...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 104, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.add_field(
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 328, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 189, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1512, in get_db_prep_save
    return connection.ops.adapt_decimalfield_value(self.to_python(value), self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 523, in adapt_decimalfield_value
    return utils.format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
  File "C:\Users\aser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 235, in format_number
    value = value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(1).scaleb(-decimal_places), context=context)
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

I've been looking but can't really find what's wrong

This is my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Users_Upload(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=4)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="Bay Area, San Francisco, California, USA")
```

and my admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Users_Upload

admin.site.register(Users_Upload)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solved it. I had to clear out all my migrations and re-migrate again.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I deleted the migrations and migrated again and it worked.